# Creating Sprite Sheet in Windows

Tags: android

I am using Wiengine for making a game in android. For better resource utilization I am creating a sprite sheet but it can be made in MAC operating system, can any one guide me on how to make a sprite sheet in Windows.

Comment: What is a zwoptex? Have you researched it? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer of my question. There is a tool available for windows to make sprite sheets. That tool is known as [texture packer](http://www.top4download.com/texturepacker/download-epnmqgth.html)